# Validation Laravel of 2 fields : first is datepicker and second is select

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have many fields on my form.
2 of them have to bind together.

The first is an datepicker and the second a select field (filled in function of date chosen).

```html
<input class="form-control pull-right" name="day_desired" id="day_desired" placeholder="Day Desired" type="text" value="{{ old('day_desired') }}">
<select id="hour_id" name="hour_id" class="form-control">
   <option value="0">--- Choose hour ---</option>
   <option value="10:00">10h00</option>
   ...
</select>
```

So I want to do this :

- If no date chosen, these 2 fields are optionals.
- If a date is chosen, the select field is required and not equal to 0 (0 is the first value of options and I use it like a label).

I had many tests with required_if, required_unless no success....

```php
return [
            'name'=>'required',
            'first_name' =>'required',
            ...

            'day_desired' =>'nullable',
            'hour_id' =>'nullable'
        ];
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `required_if` and `required_unless` checks will look for a certain condition for the value of another field. That is not what you need here.

You can use `required_with`:

```
'day_desired' =>'nullable',
'hour_id' =>'required_with:day_desired|nullable|min:1'
```

The reason that `hour_id` has to be `nullable` is that you don't want the `min:1` check to run when the `day_desired` and the `hour_id` are empty. Still, the `required_with` rule will fail, even though the field is nullable, as pointed out in [this post on GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18397#issuecomment-287524129). This behaviour was added in this release: https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v5.4.16.

Comment: Ok thank you for explanation but unfortunatly, it's not working.

If I choose a date and then I try to send my form, no error appears for the second field hour_id.
And this is it working, if I don't fill these 2 fields, no errors occurs so it is good.

Comment: Strange, this behaviour was added in Laravel 5.4. Are you perhaps using an older version?

Comment: No no my project is under Laravel 5.5

Comment: I forgot to add `day_desired` to `required_with` --> `required_with:day_desired`. Can you please try this @yasgrasdemonde (see updated answer).? Then the validator will fail.

Comment: Yes I had seen this forgetfulness and I corrected it immediately by adding day_desired to required_with. And not working as I said in my first comment.
it seems that the value 0 of my select field would be a problem, no?

Comment: That's really strange. I just tested exactly this code, and I am not able to reproduce your issue but get exactly the behaviour you need. It was added in this release: https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v5.4.16.

Comment: Ok it works ! I have to remove the value 0 of my first option in my select field. And so it works as expected.

Comment: Great! Can you please accept the answer in order to show to other users that this resolves the issue?